# Getting runtime class information from the web? Something like javap but at runtime on class loaded in memory

Tags: java, dynamic, javap

I am working with Websphere and complicated classloading issues.  I want to be able to download or print information that would normally get printed by javap (the methods, etc).

I may also need to get the raw binary class data, to perform a binary diff.

How would you do this?

Comment: There are some built in classloader diagnostics, accessibly through the console. Were they any use?

Comment: The reflection APIs (obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods() and friends), should be able to get you most of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a Servlet or JMX MBean that exposes the class to the your client.

Servlet:

```
String resourceParameter = ...;
OutputStream out = ...:
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
   .getResourceAsStream(resourceParameter)
write(input, out);
```

Client:

```
GET http://host/DiagnosticServlet?resource=your/ClassName.class
```

The resource parameter has to be your **class file** your.ClassName -> your/ClassName.class.
You can then save the file and use javap.

(I think the MBean has to encode your class file into a string (e.g. Base 64) as byte[] is not supported. But I'm not sure about that. The rest would be the same.)

If this will be deployed in production some form of authentication should be configured.